# Redirect output of unit function/method in scala as standard in for linux mail command

Tags: linux, scala

Lets say I have a unit function/method that such as the following:

```
def PrintOrders(): Unit = {
   println("stuff")
   println("things")
   anotherUnitFunctionThatPrintsThings()
    ...
  }
```

Is there a way for me to redirect the output produced in this unit command as an argument to the process or processbuilder libraries to execute the linux `mail` command using this output?

edit: just to be safe, I want this done from within the scala program and not using a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the output using your own PrintStream:

```
val s = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
Console.withOut(new PrintStream(s)) {
  PrintOrders()
}
val output = s.toString("UTF-8")
```

Then you can use that as a string for whatever.

Comment: Very interesting approach. Didn't think of it this way at all.